# Firefox + some javascript = tab with an endless spinning wheel that never finish loading (Chrome is okay!). Why?

Tags: javascript, firefox

```js
function clickMe() {
            document.write("You clicked on the Button!"); 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <input type="button" value="Button" onclick="clickMe()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Pressing the button here causes the Firefox tab loading wheel to spin forever. Why is that?

Are there any errors in the code or maybe this is some Firefox issue?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should **never** use `document.write`, and doing it some other way probably solves that issues anyway.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write` anyway?

Comment: I just didn't know I should have never used it. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling
>   `document.open()` will automatically perform a `document.open` call.
>
> Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call `document.close()`,
>   to tell the browser to finish loading the page.

So whenever you call `document.write` on a document that has already finished loading, like you're doing with an event handler, the entire document is overwritten, and `document.open` is called automatically, but as the document never finishes loading and calls `document.close`, the loading wheel keep spinning.

Apparently different browsers do different things, and it's not specifically specified wether or not they should just "hang" forever or not.

As `document.write` should generally never be used anyway, this is really not an issue, just replace it with a proper method that modifies the DOM instead of overwriting the entire document.

Comment: Thank you so much!